# Joomla - VirtueMart 1.x > Magento 2.0

Tags: virtuemart, joomla-1.5

I got a project where a client who is running a relatively big e-commerce is planing to switch from Joomla's VirtueMart 1.1 to Magento 2.0.

What is the best way to export products/customers/discounts/reviews to Magento 2.0? Are there any tools that work available or should I start writing PHP script which would map everything in CSV ?

Thank you for any info regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mikan, as you already stated in your answer, this extension only supports Magento 1.9.2 and they aren't planning to include support for Magento 2.0.

After lots of research I found alternative plugin called "[**VirtueMart to Magento**](http://goo.gl/Bs3Fmf)" for migration of VirtueMart 1.x, 2.x to Magento 2.

In comparison to Cart2Cart is a bit expensive, specialy for bigger shops because it's limited by number of entities, but as much as I tested it, it migrates all the needed fields (customers, reviews, categories, orders, products).

Answer (score 2):

There is commercial extension **[Vm2Mage](https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/vm2mage)** from Yireo.

Migrating data from VirtueMart to Magento is part of a bigger process: A new Magento site also requires a proper theme, a revision of strategy, marketing effort, perhaps CMS-capabilities. There for we advise Vm2Mage to people who want to make real use of Magento. Vm2Mage is a flexible tool ment for Magento sitebuilders, webdesigners and webdevelopers. If you want to migrate from VirtueMart to Magento, this extension is a real time-saver!

Current version     0.10.33 (Stable)
Requirements    Joomla 1.5
Joomla 1.6, 1.7 or 2.5
VirtueMart 1.1.2 or later
VirtueMart 2.0.1 or later
Magento CE 1.7 - 1.9
Magento EE 1.10 - 1.14
PHP 5.4.0 or higher (5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 7)

---

There is also official Magento extension **[Cart2Cart](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cart2cart-virtuemart-to-magento-migration.html)**

Automatically migrate your products, customers, orders and other store data from VirtueMart to Magento!

Compatible with Magento: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4.1.1, 1.4.2, 1.5, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2.0, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2

---

Because Magento 2.0 is fairly new on the market, these extensions are probably not yet compatible with it, but you can always contact extension developers and enquire about their plans to upgrade them.

Answer (score 1):

Actually we do support Magento 2.0. It is not mentioned on our extension because there is a completely new section for Magento 2 extensions on Magento Connect.

So, you can migrate from VirtueMart 1.1 to Magento 2.0 using Cart2Cart.

Best regards,
Cart2Cart Team

Comment: Sorry my bad then, somehow I must have misunderstood that Cart2Cart extension won't support Magento 2.